# Hover on <p> element to highlight geographic boundary, D3 Choropleth

Tags: html, d3.js, hover

I made a choropleth map of Chicago's 77 neighborhoods in D3.
The only challenge is, it's hard to know which neighborhood is which.
So, what I did was make divs with p elements (containing the neighborhood names) in the body of my HTML file and positioned them into a blank spot in my svg/canvas.

See a visual [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eGChw.png).

What I'm trying to do is make it so when you hover over the name, the geographic boundary of the neighborhood highlights. Somehow I need to relate the geography to the text, but I have no idea how.

Answer (score 0):

For a more robust solution, you would ideally want to add an id field to your data. This assumes that your data is some format (such as JSON). You may already have a unique identifier that you can use instead, but if not the following should work.

```
var i = 0;
for (var x in dataSet)
    dataSet[x].id = ++i; //Or i++ for zero-based indexing
```

Now it depends on how you are generating the svg elements, but ideally you are using the `enter` function of d3. In that case, just create the result of `enter` as a variable and use it to append both the path (map portion) as well as the text.

```
var dataSelect = svg.selectAll(".item").data(data.items);
var dataEnter = dataSelect.enter();
dataEnter.append("path").....
dataEnter.append("text").....text(function(d){return d.label;}) //Using text because this is drawn inside the SVG.
```

With using the `data` and `enter` functions, the created objects automatically have the id data bound to them.

This makes it a simple case of `text.id == path.id` in your `mouseover` function.

```
svg.selectAll(".itemText").on("mouseover", function(textItem){
    svg.selectAll(".item").each(function (cityItem){
    if (cityItem.id == textItem.id)
        d3.select(this).style("fill", "green");
    else
        d3.select(this).style("fill", function(d){return d.color;});
  })
});
```

I've done this in a fiddle which you can see [here](https://jsfiddle.net/armarchm/1ebLf89b/)

Note that this does not use `p` elements because ideally, if you're using SVG then you probably should use `text` elements. If you *have to* use `p` elements, then you can still use this general technique, but instead using `p.text()` as the matching factor on `mouseover` instead of `id`, assuming that the name is bound to your path data somewhere.

Comment: I'm beginning to wrap my head around your answer. How would I go through this example if the data were external? I know I'd have to load it with an AJAX request, d3.json(source, callback)...but how would that work?